# Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in type cast while trying to open a box in Hive

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am trying to open a box in Hive db in my flutter app. Below is the code:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
 
  late Box<Item> storyBox;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
  }

  Future openBox() async {
    final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(document.path);
    Hive.registerAdapter(ItemAdapter());
    storyBox = await Hive.openBox<Item>(storyBoxName);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeDependencies() async {
    const url = 'https://shaparak-732ff.firebaseio.com/items.json';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    await openBox();
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
      storyBox.put(key, value);
      Item? story = storyBox.get(key);
      print(story?.title);
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

And here is what debug console returns when I run the app:

```
    Restarted application in 8,727ms.
E/flutter (25550): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in type cast
E/flutter (25550): #0      ItemAdapter.read
package:database/item.g.dart:25
E/flutter (25550): #1      BinaryReaderImpl.read
package:hive/…/binary/binary_reader_impl.dart:326
E/flutter (25550): #2      BinaryReaderImpl.readFrame
package:hive/…/binary/binary_reader_impl.dart:274
E/flutter (25550): #3      FrameHelper.framesFromBytes
package:hive/…/binary/frame_helper.dart:21
```

I am opening a box of type "Item". I don't know what is the cause of this problem but my assumption is that it is related to the file: `item.g.dart` which is `TypeAdapterGenerator`:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'item.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class ItemAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Item> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  Item read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return Item(
      title: fields[0] as String?,
      author: fields[1] as String?,
      id: fields[2] as String?,
      category: fields[3] as String?,
      content: fields[4] as String?,
      startColor: fields[5] as String?,
      endColor: fields[6] as String?,
      isFavorite: fields[7] as bool,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Item obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(8)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.title)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.author)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.id)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.category)
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..write(obj.content)
      ..writeByte(5)
      ..write(obj.startColor)
      ..writeByte(6)
      ..write(obj.endColor)
      ..writeByte(7)
      ..write(obj.isFavorite);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ItemAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

Below is the `item.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part 'item.g.dart';
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Item with ChangeNotifier {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String? title;
  @HiveField(1)
  final String? author;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String? id;
  @HiveField(3)
  final String? category;
  @HiveField(4)
  final String? content;
  @HiveField(5)
  final String? startColor;
  @HiveField(6)
  final String? endColor;
  @HiveField(7)
  bool isFavorite;
  Item({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.author,

    @required this.id,
    @required this.category,
    @required this.content,
    @required this.startColor,
    @required this.endColor,
    this.isFavorite = false,

  });
  void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
   // isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Check the log, the error pointed to which line?

Comment: line 25 of ItemAdapter.read

Comment: check your json output..I suspect `fields[7]` is `String`, not `bool`?

Answer (score 0):

What does this line return ?
`final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;`
Is the extracted data returning string type or bool type for the column you are having issues with ?
I m suspecting it is all strings but you are trying to get a bool out of it.
You may need a custom from json to create your object.

Answer (score 0):

Your old data of app residing that causing error.
First uninstall your app then install fresh, it will solve your problem.

What happened in my case:
we were working on two branches.
One developer added field on **typeId 4** on branch A.
I was also adding field on **typeId 4** on branch B.
But I installed app from branch A. And then I changed my branch to B and installing again app.
But currently app has data from branch A, therefore issue occurred at my end.

I took a pull from Branch A and **then I added my field on typeId 5**.
Problem Solved, if this is the case.